# Files not being copied to AFP volume when copying through the Finder

Tags: macos, nas, afp, readynas

I am trying to copy files from my MacBook's hard disk to my NAS. The latter is a ReadyNAS Duo and is mounted as an AFP volume. The files are about 5MB each and I copy them by selecting in a Finder window all the files that I need and then dropping them onto the destination directory. Almost always some of the files do not get copied to the NAS. For example, if I select 200 files and then start the copying, everything looks at the beginning normal (while the copying takes place the Finder window for the **destination** directory is updated to show 200 files while it was empty before), but after the copying ends the destination directory shows less than 200 files (let's say 190). If I copy again the same 200 files to the NAS, without replacing already copied files, the remaining 10 files are usually copied correctly. In a few cases, I have to repeat the process a third time. Notice that the Finder does not give **any** warning that some of the files have not been copied at any stage. I am wondering if this a known problem with AFP and the Finder and/or if there is something that I can do to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've used a variety of AFP servers and never seen this problem, although I've never used a ReadyNAS. This sounds to me like a badly broken AFP server implementation that's misleading the AFP client.

I suppose it could be filesystem corruption on the ReadyNAS. You could try running a filesystem check on its disks.

What version of Mac OS X? What do the `/var/log/system.log` and `/var/log/kernel.log` on the Mac say? What does the AFP server log on the ReadyNAS say?

Comment: Mac OS X 10.5.8. `/var/log/system.log` does not contain anything related to the copies. `/var/log/kernel.log` does not exist on my system. And on the NAS `/var/log/netatalk.log` also has nothing related to the copies. Perhaps I can force the server to log more information?